# Difference between Kotlin arrow IO, IO.fx, IO !effect

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, arrow-kt

I am trying to use arrow in kotlin

Arrow has three functions

```
IO {}
IO.fx {}
IO.fx { !effect}
```

I want to know the difference between these. I know IO.fx and IO.fx {!effect} help us use side effects but then whats the difference between the two and why would I use one over the other

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this is going to change shortly, on version 0.11.X:

- `IO { }` is a constructor that takes a suspend function, so you can call any suspend function inside. It's a shortcut for `IO.effect { }`

```
suspend fun bla(): Unit = ...

fun myIO(): IO<Unit> = IO { bla() }

fun otherIO(): IO<Unit> = IO.effect { bla() }
```

- `IO.fx { }` is the same as `IO` except it adds a few DSL functions that are shortcuts for other APIs of IO. The most important one is `!` or `bind`, which executes another IO inside.

```
fun myIO(): IO<Unit> = IO.fx { bla() }

fun nestIO(): IO<IO<Unit>> = IO.fx { myIO() }

fun unpackIO(): IO<Unit> = IO.fx { !myIO() }
```

Another function it enables is the constructor `effect` from the first point. So what you're effectively doing is adding an additional layer of wrapping that may not be necessary.

```
fun inefficientNestIO(): IO<IO<Unit>> = IO.fx { effect { bla() } }

fun inefficientUnpackedIO(): IO<Unit> = IO.fx { !effect { bla() } }
```

We frequently see that `inefficientUnpackedIO` from people who come to the support channels, and it's easily replaceable by just `IO { bla() }`.

Why have two ways of doing the same in `effect` and `fx`? It's something we're looking to improve on the next releases. We recommend using the *least powerful* abstraction wherever possible, so reserve `fx` only when using other `IO`-based APIs such as scheduling or parallelization.

```
IO.fx {
  val id = getUserIdSuspend()
  val friends: List<User> = 
    !parMapN(
      userFriends(id),
      IO { userProfile(id) },
      ::toUsers
    )
  !friends.parTraverse(IO.applicative()) { user ->
   IO { broadcastStatus(user) } 
  }
}
```